# MySQL database query returns empty result

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I am doing a data migration and getting empty result of simple query with one join. Following is the query

```
Select * from users u INNER JOIN temp_users tu ON tu.uid = u.uid
```

There are hundreds of records which have same uid in both tables, but this query returns only one record.

Following is the structure of tables

```
users table
uid:  varchar(50)   utf8_general_ci         Yes     NULL 

temp_users table
uid: varchar(50)    utf8_general_ci         Yes     NULL
```

Comment: May be you have only one matched record.

Comment: Try Left Join instead of Inner Join

Comment: Post some data from your tables if you're sure you should have matches...

Comment: Yes. Post data of at least one row from each table that you think should join that aren't joining.

Comment: I doubt You have problem somewhere else... Not with the query. You must get results if you really have some rows in both tables with equal id

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Select * from users u INNER JOIN temp_users tu ON trim(upper(tu.uid)) = trim(upper(u.uid));
```

May there is no matched id b/w the tables.. confirm using..

```
Select u.id,tu.id from users u LEFT JOIN temp_users tu ON trim(upper(tu.uid)) = trim(upper(u.uid));
```

Comment: Left Join is giving results. This means they are not matching but when I search them on users table it is present.

Comment: @user1791096: problem is same uid records are not present in temp_users table

Comment: I have checked it by searching records in temp_users table. They are present there but when I use JOIN then i does not show results. Even subquery is also not giving results. What should I do ??? I have also restarted mysql many times but don't work.

Comment: User ids that I am trying to match are in this format: 66b69e14-5452-4f40-8fef-ffff9245da7e.

Comment: What ever, as per the given example they should match.. OP has to post some data from table.